# Python match pattern to rename file

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, file-rename

I have couple of files with like this, `llm_rc_v3212.xml, llm_ds_v3232.xml`.
Names can be anything. however, common parameter would be`_v3212`. I want to match this number and replace it (ideally renaming the file).

How can i match this pattern with regex? I am trying to use `re.sub`, but not able to figure yet.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How exactly did you use `re.sub`?

Comment: That common parameter could be matches with regex `_v\d+`

Comment: What do you wish to rename the number as?

Comment: @Paco That will also match `_v0` in `abc_v0x_v123.xml`

Comment: Indeed, but it will work with the given examples. If the filenames can take another form @tgcloud please provide those.

Comment: @PacoH.: I have couple of files with `llm_v232_uc.xml` pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example. Take into account that depending on other filenames the regex might need to be changed.

```
import re

FILENAME_VERSION_REGEX = re.compile(r'_v(\d)+')


def rename(filename, replacement):
    full_replacement = r'_v{}'.format(replacement)
    new_filename = FILENAME_VERSION_REGEX.sub(full_replacement, filename)
    return new_filename
```

Tested with the filenames you gave:

```
>>> rename('llm_rc_v3212.xml', 1)
'llm_rc_v1.xml'

>>> rename('llm_ds_v3232.xml', 2)
'llm_ds_v2.xml'

>>> rename('llm_v232_uc.xml', 3)
'llm_v3_uc.xml'
```

Comment: Thanks for Clear Explanation.! I am newbie ..!